# Pandas; Python - Perform aggregation over the rest of the rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm looking for a way to apply a transformation over a column of my DF, such that the transformation is performed over the entire dataset **except** each specific row.

For example, consider the column:

| A |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

I would like to transform each value, such that the new value is the mean of the rest of the rows. i.e. all the rows except this one. For example, the new value of the first row (1) will be the mean of (2,3,4,5). The new value of the second row (2) will be the mean of (1,3,4,5) and so on.

In this specific case, I could, of course, calculate the overall mean, and then subtract the value of column A, divided by its length. By doing that, I essentially calculated the aggregation overall, and then subtracted the contribution of this specific row. The problem is that in my case, the aggregation is more complicated than just mean, and so I was wondering if there's a way to perform "aggregation over the rest".

Thank you in advance for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the mean, an easy and efficient solution would be to do it manually by getting the sum of all, subtracting self, and dividing by the number of rows -1:

```
df['mean_other'] = df['A'].rsub(df['A'].sum()).div(len(df)-1)
```

Output:

```
   A  mean_other
0  1        3.50
1  2        3.25
2  3        3.00
3  4        2.75
4  5        2.50
```

A more generic method that would work with any operation is to convert to 2D array, mask the diagonal and perform your computation(s):

```
a = np.repeat(df['A'].to_numpy()[None], len(df), axis=0).astype(float)
np.fill_diagonal(a, np.nan)
df['mean_other'] = np.nanmean(a, axis=1)
df['median_other'] = np.nanmedian(a, axis=1)
df['std_other'] = np.nanstd(a, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   A  mean_other  median_other  std_other
0  1        3.50           3.5   1.118034
1  2        3.25           3.5   1.479020
2  3        3.00           3.0   1.581139
3  4        2.75           2.5   1.479020
4  5        2.50           2.5   1.118034
```

Intermediate array `a`:

```
array([[nan,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 1., nan,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  2., nan,  4.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3., nan,  5.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4., nan]])
```

Answer (score 0):

> so I was wondering if there's a way to perform "aggregation over the rest".

For custom aggregation functions, you could roll over each row and retrieve the rest of the dataframe before returning the aggregated value of your choice.

```py
def agg_func(x, df):
    res_df = df[~(df.index == x.index[0])]
    return res_df.mean()  # Custom agg function of your choice

df.rolling(1)["A"].agg(agg_func, df)
```

Although I'm not sure of the performance of such a solution

Comment: this isn't using all **other** rows, but all **previous** (or following) rows here ;)

Comment: Indeed, didn't read the question properly.